# Why it doesn't return?? PHP

Tags: php

I can't understand and I seek for help=( 
Here is my code:

```
        $add_article = $this->M_articles->Add($_POST['title'], $_POST['content']);
        echo "sd;flksdf;lksdfl;";
        $add_article2 = true;
        if ($add_article)
        {
            echo 'Article Added!';
            header("Location:index.php");
            die();
        }
        else
            die('Error adding article');
```

this is function "Add" from M_Articles:

```
        public function Add($title, $content)
{
    /*
    $title = trim($title);
    $content = trim($content);

    if ($title == '')
        return false;

    //запрос
    $object = array();
    $object['title'] = $title;
    $object['content'] = $content;

    $this->msql->Insert('articles', $object);
    */

    return true;
}
```

The thing is...even if I comment everything from function "Add" and leave only "return true"... it wouldn't redirect me to index.php. Moreover, it doesn't even echo anything (even those "sd;fkfdsf.." string). The script just dies for some reason. I can't get where is the problem, can some1 explain to newbie what's the problem and how it should be fixed? If you need additional info, i'll provide it.

update: Maybe it's important...but if I delete those comment "/* */" things, it'd correctly add article to a DataBase. But then the script dies=/

update:
ok, now it says: "Notice: Undefined variable: result in Z:\home\myblog\www\c\M_MSQL.php on line 86"
here's my code for M_MSQL on line 86:

```
            public function Insert($table, $object)
{
    $columns = array();
    $values = array();

    foreach ($object as $key => $value)
    {
        $key = mysql_real_escape_string($key . '');
        $columns[] = $key;

        if ($value === null)
        {
            $values[] = "'$value'";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value . '');
            $values[] = "'$value'";
        }

    }
    $columns_s = implode(',', $columns);
    $values_s = implode(',', $values);

    $query = "INSERT INTO $table ($columns_s) VALUES ($values_s)";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result)
        die(mysql_error());

    return mysql_insert_id();
}
```

Comment: you cant output anything before header. if you had error checking on you would see error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is you are outputing things, so you have a notice : "Headers already sent".

If you remove the "echo" stuff, you'll be alright :

```
    if ($add_article)
    {
        header('Location: /index.php?article_added=1');
    }
```

Comment: There are no notice. There are just nothing=) And it should have echoed at least something. I mean the first echo just after the call of "Add" function. It doesn't echo=/

Comment: @Rishka white page of death, error reporting\display are off, turn them on `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: If you didn't configure your server to show notices, then you won't see any. Though about the echo not showing, it's weird, have you tried using `var_dump($add_article);die();` before the `if` statement?

Comment: @Dagon ok...that's smth new for me. Thanks for advice, it has shown the error: Notice: Undefined variable: result in Z:\home\myblog\www\c\M_MSQL.php on line 86

Comment: Please show us this M_MSQL.php. look for any credentials in it and remove them before doing so though.

Comment: @Loïc just did! Still can't get the mistake. It was working fine untill I started to put it into OOP

Comment: Btw, line 86 is: "if (!$result)"

Comment: try using : `if(!isset($result) || !$result)` instead. This is weird though.

Comment: @Loïc ok...there are no more error-message if I use your condition... But it the script still doesn't work=( Even if i comment everything in "Add" function and make it return true...sctipr still doesn't work after call of that function. I can't get it, srsly. No echo's, no "vardump". Nothing. Maybe I should reinstall php?

Comment: Because the add method returns false. Your insert is not working. Now I don't get why it doesn't output the 'Error adding article' message.

Comment: But i've commented everything inside and left only "return true"! And i've checked twice if it's the proper file i'm editing. And yes - i keep saving changes.

Comment: Ok...i've checked the script on my ubuntu machine. It works! Well..it doesn't but it says that headers are already send - that's becouse of those "echo" things. I can't get it. What's wrong?

Comment: you can't use `header` when you have already used `echo` because when you use `echo` the server generates response headers so you can't edit them and send others. remove the `echo` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Ye, I know! I wanted to say that i can't understand why the same script works fine on ubuntu machine, but doesn't work on my windows machine. Blah...anyway, that's another story, i suspect. Thx for the help!

Comment: There is a world between ubuntu and windows. Glad you finally have this working anyway. Have fun tinkering with PHP! ++ mate.